# when start apache service wamp could not execute menu item access is deined

Tags: apache, windows-8, wamp, folder-permissions

Environment:

```
Windows 8
WAMP 2.4 x86
Installed all those C++ lib packages saw in other posts
```

Troubleshooting done:

```
No error logged in either SQL / Apache error logs
Did  not see any WAMP related service report in the windows event viewer
port 80 is NOT in use
Re-installed WAMP after install the packages
```

Error:

```
Received no error when try to click start serivice for mySQL, 
but it will not start anyway, 
since after I clicked it, the stop icon for mySQL is still grayed out.
and the main problem will be error message popup 
when start apache service wamp could not execute menu item access is deined
```

I am pretty confused at this point as all the others nly have error message of service not starts, but I have error of access is denied as well when start Apache.

I don't know how to troubleshoot further to find the core issue....

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Silly Me.... forgot to copy the files INSIDE the www and data folders into the new location lololololol

The only step I missed..... Now it works perfectly :)

SO yea, whoever follow about steps and done above + copying those files in the original folder, the setup definitely will work!